# Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.kspub.mongodb.net

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

my web app cannot connect to mongo dB atlas and it shows me the following error

```
Failed to connect to the database :Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.kspub.mongodb.net
2022-01-18T16:58:59.817138+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:34) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.kspub.mongodb.net
2022-01-18T16:58:59.817138+00:00 app[web.1]: at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:210:19)
2022-01-18T16:58:59.817139+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnD4w.jpg)

even though it works locally and connects to the database, here is my code
https://github.com/yara121/mern-app/blob/main/server/src/app.js

Answer (score 3):

Visit you mongodb atlas dashboard >> Go to your network access >> Edit your current whitelisted IP address >> click "Allow access from anywhere"

This did the trick for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following solution helped me. In mongodb atlas Dashboard -> Database -> Connect -> Connect your application -> I copied the link in step 2 - `mongodb+srv://root:<password>@YOUR_APP_NAME.waoe4uy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. Then I pasted this link into the backend of my project in the settings file. In my case, this is the default.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Your dbRUL is correct according to your database. I have same this issue and I correct this by changing dbRUL